# I want to insert data in txt format file into sql database

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a file named queryservices.txt. The data in it ";" divided with, can i write directly to sql database

C:\queryservices.txt
file content;
;STATE;4  RUNNING

(sorry i'm trying to learn sqli by myself, the codes may sound silly)

Codes I've developed so far

```
BULK INSERT dbo.query
FROM 'queryservices.txt'
WITH 
  (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';'
  )
```

Comment: No, you can't do this directly. You need some form of CSV parser that creates insert statements for you.

Comment: Thank you for your support Mark. I will search

Comment: It looks like tag "firebird" in this question is a mistake. Your code is obviously for MS SQL.